# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a program which can solve the 8-Puzzle problem.I am using the A* algorithm to find the solution.
I have reviewed my code many times and also tried making some changes.
Even my friends tried to help me find the bug,but they couldn't. I still don't understand where i went wrong.I used javadocs to see if I did something wrong,even that din't solve my problem.  I have created three classes to solve this problem.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solver implements Iterable<State>
{
    ArrayList<State> queue,solQueue;
    public int sol[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 0 } };
    int temp[][],i;
    int moves;
    int leastPriority,removeIndex;
    State removeTemp;
    public Solver(State initial)
    {
        queue = new ArrayList<State>();
        solQueue = new ArrayList<State>();
        queue.ensureCapacity(16);
        solQueue.ensureCapacity(16);
        temp = new int[3][3];
    i=1;
    leastPriority = 100;
    removeTemp=initial;
    queue.add(removeTemp);
    Iterator<State> qu = queue.iterator();
    while(removeTemp.m!=sol)
    {
        leastPriority = 100;
        i=0;
        queue.iterator();
        for (State s : queue) 
        {
            if((s.mh + s.count) <leastPriority)
            {
                leastPriority = (s.mh + s.count);
                removeIndex = i;
            }
            if(qu.hasNext())
                i++;
        }
        for(State s : removeTemp.neighbours() )
        {
            queue.add(s);
        }
        removeTemp=queue.remove(removeIndex);
        solQueue.add(removeTemp);
    }
    this.moves();
    this.solution();
}
public int moves() 
{
    System.out.print("Solution found out in "+ moves+" moves");
    moves = removeTemp.count;
    return moves;
}
public Iterable<State> solution() 
{
    for(State s : solQueue)
    {
        System.out.println(s.m);
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return solQueue;
}
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public Iterator iterator() {
    return null;
}
}
```

And the JVM is throwing an exception.

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:  0,Size: 0
     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
     at Solver.<init>(Solver.java:41)
     at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

What i don't understand is that how can the size of the ArrayList be 1 when i have explicitly state it as 16.

The State Class has the heuristic function which is suppose to make the algorithm efficient.The following is the State Class.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;

  public class State implements Iterable<State>
  {
   public int sol[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 0 } };
   int m[][], bi, bj, count, priority, si, sj;
   int i,j,tempm[][];
   int mh = 0;
   boolean isInitialState, isRepeatedState;
   State previousState, tempState;
   ArrayList<State> neighbourStates;

   public State(State s, int c, int[][] array) 
{
    neighbourStates = new ArrayList<State>();
    neighbourStates.ensureCapacity(16);

    tempState =this;
    m = new int[3][3];
    m=array;

    if (s == null) 
    {
        isInitialState = true;
        count = 0;
        previousState =null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        previousState = s;
        count = c+1;
    }

    this.findZero();
    this.manhattanHeuristic();
}

private void findZero() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(m[i][j]==0)
            {
                bi=i;
                bj=j;
            }
        }
}

private void manhattanHeuristic() {
    int n = 1;
    mh = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Z: for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if ((i == bi) && (j == bj)) {
                continue Z;
            }

            else if (m[i][j] == n) {
                n++;
            }

            else {
                this.getSolutionIndex();
                mh = mh + Math.abs(i - si) + Math.abs(j - sj);
            }

        }
}

void getSolutionIndex() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == 0) {
                si = i;
                sj = j;
            }
        }

}

public Iterable<State> neighbours()
{
    tempm = m;
    this.up();
    if(!(equals(tempm)))
    {
        tempState = new State(this,count,tempm);
        neighbourStates.add(tempState);
    }

    this.down();
    if(!(equals(tempm)))
    {
        tempState = new State(this,count,tempm);
        neighbourStates.add(tempState);
    }

    this.left();
    if(!(equals(tempm)))
    {
        tempState = new State(this,count,tempm);
        neighbourStates.add(tempState);
    }

    this.right();
    if(!(equals(tempm)))
    {
        tempState = new State(this,count,tempm);
        neighbourStates.add(tempState);
    }

    return neighbourStates;     

}

public boolean equals(int s[][])
{
    if((isInitialState==false)&&(previousState.m == s))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

@Override
public Iterator<State> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void up()
{
    if ((bi > 1) && (bi < 2) && (bj < 3)&& (bj > 1))
    {
        i = bi;
        i = i + 1;
        this.move(i,bj);
    }

}

public void  down()
{
    if ((bi > 2) && (bi < 3) && (bj < 3) && (bj > 1)) 
    {
        i = bi;
        i = i - 1;
        this.move(i,bj);
    }
}

public void left()
{
    if ((bi > 1) && (bi < 3) && (bj < 2)&& (bj > 1)) {
        j = bj;
        j = j + 1;
        this.move(bi, j);
    }
}

public void right()
{
    if ((bi > 1) && (bi < 3) && (bj < 3) && (bj > 2)) {
        j = bj;
        j = j - 1;
        this.move(bi, j);

    }

}

public void move(int x, int y) {
    {
        tempm = m;
    }
    if ((tempm[x + 1][y] == 0) || (tempm[x - 1][y] == 0) || (tempm[x][y + 1] == 0)|| (tempm[x][y - 1] == 0)) {
        tempm[bi][bj] = tempm[x][y];
        tempm[x][y] = 0;
        bi = x;
        bj = y;



    }
}
```

}

And the finally the class with the main function.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[][] tiles = new int[3][3];
     System.out.println("Enter the elements");
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            tiles[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
     State initial = new State(null,0,tiles);
     Solver solver = new Solver(initial);
     solver.solution();

     System.out.println("Minimum number of moves = " + solver.moves());

     }

}
```

Comment: You se the **capacity** to 16, not the size. Capacity is not the same thing as size.

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't do the actual solving in the constructor. Constructors are used to prepare/initialize some variables. You might consider moving the logic part to some sort of "solve" method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What i don't understand is that how can the size of the ArrayList be 1 when i have explicitly state it as 16.

You did not set the size of the `ArrayList` to 16. You've set the capacity:

```
queue.ensureCapacity(16);
solQueue.ensureCapacity(16);
```

This does not make the `ArrayList` have a size of 16.

An `ArrayList` has an array to hold its data. When you add more elements to the `ArrayList` and its internal array is full, it will have to allocate a larger array and copy the content of what it currently holds plus the new element.

The *capacity* of the `ArrayList` is the minimum size that the internal array has. You can use `ensureCapacity` to make sure that the `ArrayList` doesn't have to resize too often (resizing and copying the content is an expensive operation). So, `ensureCapacity` is a call you make to make it work effiently.

It does not make the `ArrayList` have 16 elements; it only makes sure that the `ArrayList` has room for at least 16 elements.

If you want the `ArrayList` to have 16 elements, you'll have to add those elements one by one.

Answer (score 1):

**Size of the collection and the capacity are 2 different concepts.**

- capacity represents the maximum size of items a collection can hold without a reallocation.
- size represents the current number of items in the collection.

**`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is saying that you are trying to access an item with index that does not exist in the collection.**

Comment: @Jesper Doesn't the first for loop in the solver class ensure that value of i will never be >= to the size?

Comment: The exception is thrown on the line removeTemp = queue.remove(removeIndex);

Comment: True,but removeIndex = i ,then how can remove index be more than i?

Comment: We would need to debug and understand what the program is doing. We gave him the clues what is wrong.

Comment: I value you answer,but i ready knew that the exception is thrown on the line removeTemp = queue.remove(removeIndex);But can You help in finding the bug?

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code in Solver.java

if(!queue.isEmpty())
    removeTemp=queue.remove(removeIndex);
else
    break;